# Boto3 sts in Lambda hanging after adding networking details

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda, boto3

I have a python lambda function which needs to get the account number that it is running out of. When I had no details of the 'Network' tab set in the AWS console for Lambda it could get the account okay doing this:

```
AccountNumber = boto3.client('sts').get_caller_identity()['Account']
```

Now that I have configured a VPC, subnets, and a security group under the Network tab, this specific boto call for sts loops indefinitely. After some time I get an error from Lambda that the function timed out.

Is there a setting in a security group which can cause a boto3 call to loop like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely being caused by you not having rules in your VPC security group to allow amazon traffic out. When making boto3 or aws cli calls through botocore, the request gets sent out to the internet, not over LAN.

In order to allow botocore calls to work you'll need to open up the CIDR blocks owned by AWS. That list can be downloaded [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html)

Comment: I downloaded that ip-ranges.json. Do I need all of those ranges (for each region I run out of) in my Outbound rules for Lambda?

I also tried getting the account number from the metadata (169.254.169.254 url) which seems to have run into a similar issue.